# Recent Posts CSS row layout design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to output my most recent posts (on wordpress), the code works, however I'm struggling to produce a working template/design the way I want it to look. I've tried various different ways, for example divs, ul, span, but just cannot get it right/perfect.

I've pasted what I have below, but I'm more after a working css/grid, so I'll refit my code/css into the new layout. The image size is max 150x150px, with padding lets say 200x200 is the image box.

[desired result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U6St.png)

```
        $output = '
<' . $inner_wrapper . ' class="' . implode( ' ', $class ) . '">
<div class="rp_image">'. $image .'</div>
<div class="rp_title"><h5>'. $title .'</h5>'. $comments_link .'</div>
<div class="rp_titleinfo">'. $author .'</div>
<div class="rp_cattags">'. $category_display_text .'</div>
<div class="rp_content">' . $date . $excerpt . $content .'</div>
</' . $inner_wrapper . '>
';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/dyOzpKp

The important bit is that you if you add a wrapper around the title, author, category and tags, it's easier to manipulate them.

Flex works for me to manage the layout, but you could use something else if you wanted.

HTML

```
<div class="inner-wrapper">
 <div class="rp_image">
  image here
 </div>
 <div class="meta_wrap">
  <div class="rp_title">title here</div>
  <div class="rp_titleinfo">author here</div>
  <div class="rp_cattags">tags here</div>
  <div class="rp_content">content here</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.inner-wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.rp_image span {
 margin: 20px;
}


@media (min-width: 500px) {
 .inner-wrapper {
  flex-direction: row;
 }
}
```

Comment: The code you shared here and your codepen are not exactly the same, however the desired result looks good. I had to remove " flex-direction: column;" for it to work on my website, I'm not sure why or what was causing the image to go above the boxes, but at this point the results after tweaking to my needs basically does the job. P.S. I gave you positive feedback but my account has low reputation so will not show.

Comment: Excellent @zavakz, I'm pleased this has got you unstuck.  > The code you shared here and your codepen are not exactly the same .. yes, codepen has some styling that was for illustration only. And maybe you needed to remove the flex-direction line because I was assuming your Wordpress theme might be mobile first. Not a big deal though, iit sounds like you are good to take it from here which is the important thing ;)